# “He keeps me telling a truth” “He keeps me waking up at night”

Tags: grammar, expressions, american-english, phrases, british-english

Instead of saying “He keeps telling me a truth” “He keeps waking me up at night”
Can i say  “He keeps me telling a truth” “He keeps me waking up at night”?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change the order and keep the meaning.

Unlike some other languages (most notably Latin), most English nouns are *not inflected*. Whether a particular noun is a subject or direct object or indirect object is entirely dependent on its placement in a sentence; its form remains the same regardless.

- He keeps **telling me** a truth.
  ...means "he continuously (or repeatedly) gives me information that is true."
- He keeps **me telling** a truth.
  ...means "He continuously (or repeatedly) *influences me* so that **I say** something that is true."

In the first sentence "me" is the indirect object of the verb "[keeps] telling." He is telling a truth; "me" is the person he is telling the truth **to**.

In the second sentence "me" actually acts almost as the *subject* of the fragment "me telling a truth," which as a whole is the direct object of the verb "keeps." Or you could look at as "me" being the direct object of "keeps" and "telling a truth" the indirect object.

The same is true of your second example.

Comment: You could say (if you were religious) that 'Jesus keeps me telling **the** truth' (e.g. when Satan wants you to tell lies). If someone **kept telling me a truth**, e.g. that cheats never prosper, I'd pretty soon get tired of it. It's an odd expression. Does he provide a supply of truths, like a fortune cookie dispenser?

Comment: Thank you and what does "He keeps me singing" mean?